# How to ignore line breaks in file handling

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there any way to skip line breaks while reading a text file?

For example, lets say I have two text files, `input.text` and `output.text`.

My `input.text` file look like this:

```
welcome to stackoverflow<line break here>
another sentence
.
.
.
```

I read the first line from `input.text` and write some part of the line to `output.text`.

But when I read the second line after the line break, my first line gets lost in the text file.

What should I do?

To read the file I use this code:

```
ifstream input.open("input.text");
while(input)
{
    getline(input,string);
}
```

and to write

```
ofstream output;
output<<string;`
```

Comment: Umm what? maybe knowing the keycode for the enter button is 13...

Comment: I can't really understand what the question is asking. 1) What did you try? 2) What did you expect to happen? 3) What actually happened?

Comment: basically i try to made a scanner for my practice 
and i read code from text file and write the token to output file
but my problem is when i encounter enter key in input text file all of my token which already write in the output file are delete. why ?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has nothing to do with the enter key and everything to do with how you are reading/writing from the file. Your code apparently looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
     std::string string;
     std::ifstream input("input.text");

     while (input) { // bad
         std::getline(input, string);
     }

     std::ofstream output("output.text");
     output << string;
}
```

The "while" loop overwrites `string` for each line. If you had 3 lines of text, at the end of the while loop, `string` would contain only the last line of the input file.

What you perhaps want to do is something more like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
     std::string string;
     std::ifstream input("input.text");
     std::ofstream output("output.text");

     while (std::getline(input, string)) {
         output << string;
     }
}
```

Here is a simpler version using cin and cout:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
     std::string string;
     while (std::getline(std::cin, string)) {
         std::cout << string;
     }
}
```

As written, the "\n" at the end of each line goes missing: http://ideone.com/0FhEyj you can fix this by changing the output line to be

```
          std::cout << string << "\n";
```